# Multi Auth Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have just created multiple authentication laravel sucessfully. When i use these statement below, it has a little proplem.

```
   @if(Auth::guard('student')->check())
                    <li><span style="color: white">Xin chào </span><a href="#" >{{Auth::guard('student')->student()->name}}</a></li>
  @else
                    <li><a href="{{route('student.login')}}" >Login</a>
                    </li>
 @endif
```

This Error is :

```
Method student does not exist.
```

Yes, i haven't yet created method student. 
But if i change as `{{Auth::guard('student')->user()->name}}`.That's okay, it will display that name.
I don't know where it is i have to create `student` Method.

Comment: `{{Auth::guard('student')->student()->name}}`, take a look at `student()`

Comment: it happens error. syntax error, unexpected '**' (T_POW), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the @if statement, you've already checked that a `user` with the guard `'student'` is logged in, you don't need to check for that again, hence you can do something like this and it should work:

```
 @if(Auth::guard('student')->check())
    <li><span style="color: white">Xin chào </span><a href="#" >{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
 @else
    <li><a href="{{route('student.login')}}" >Login</a></li>
 @endif
```

Comment: your statement will output the name attribute from Users table. my issue is i want to output data from Student table. That's reason why i use multi auth laravel

Comment: So i have just gotten my own way. only {{Auth::guard('student')->user()->name}}

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding here, {{ Auth::user()->name }} will output the authenticated user, regardless of their model/table, so if you have a student logged in, this will out their name, if you have a normal user logged in, this will also output their name, as I said in the answer as long as you're inside that specific @if statement,

And as for {{ Auth::guard('student')->user() }}, this doesn't mean you're getting a user from the Students table, it just means you're retrieving a user that has a guard named 'student', these are two very different things.